# React Native got View is not defined but actually already defined the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've got an error when creating new component in React Native

I don't know what causes this error because I already declare the View component

[image: An error]

```
"react-native": "0.65.1"
```

the code in the component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Styles from './Styles';
import CommonUtils from '../../components/base/CommonUtils';
import Constant from '../../constants/Constant';

class FrequentlyAskedQuestion extends React.Component {

  navigationOptions = (route, navigation) => {
    return CommonUtils.getBackNavigationHeader(route, navigation, Constant.HEADER_TITLE.FAQ, 1, false, true);
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setOptions(this.navigationOptions(this.props.route, this.props.navigation));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          asda
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default FrequentlyAskedQuestion;
```

Comment: this shouldnt be the case @HendyCrcs

Answer (score 0):

Tried exactly with your code,couldnt replicate the error

https://snack.expo.dev/@gaurav1995/gnarly-marshmallows

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';


class FrequentlyAskedQuestion extends React.Component {

  navigationOptions = (route, navigation) => {
    return null
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // this.props.navigation.setOptions(this.navigationOptions(this.props.route, this.props.navigation));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          asda
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default FrequentlyAskedQuestion;
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I made a mistake in the stack navigator of importing the component, it already solved

from
`import FrequentlyAskedQuestion from '../features/faq/faq';`

to `import FrequentlyAskedQuestion from '../features/faq/Faq';`